# AccordionPanel Primefaces: Group tittle and content in DIV wrapper together in tab

Tags: primefaces

According to primefaces showcase AccordionPanel 
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/accordionPanel.xhtml

I have a need to group title and content into one DIV tag **for styling box-shadow** when it's opened. But It seem there is no customise for it in show case

You can see in the image **title and content** in seperate div

How can I achieve it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't. JSF components mostly generate rigid tag structure, you can't change it. Even if you could force your markup, it would break the component.

I suggest rethinking your styling instead. Maybe you could do offset box-shadows to header and content, so that they would look like one. Or you could add a transparent absolutely positioned div on top of header and content, and apply box-shadow to it instead.

Comment: Changing the generated xhtml is possible by overriding the renderer of the compoment, but this might indeed break functionality of the component. The latter is true btw for javascript ui frameworks too. Your suggestion to try offset shadows is a good one! Upvoted...